# Why is my xml layout not working for multiple screens?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've used a relative layout, done all my measurements in dp, and created images for all the various pixel densities. Despite using density independent pixels my images are not shrinking adequately to smaller displays. Why are my density independent pixel dimensions not working?

I'm aiming to make the ldpi look like the xldpi below.

**xldpi Display (how I want my display to look)**
[image: xldpi Display]

**ldpi Display**

[image: lpdi]

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton0"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nextHandButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nextHandButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextHandButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton" />

<en.deco.android.livehud.ImageButtonWithContextMenuInfo
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextHandButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_box" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_seatButton"/>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/table_test"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_table" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/nextHandButton"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/table"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acc_nextHandButton"
    android:src="@drawable/next_button_test" />
```

Comment: Screen density has nothing to do with screen size, and your previews are changing both. Beyond that, you need to explain what you are expecting to see, and how that ties into your XML layout.

Comment: I've added what I'm aiming for, it does appear I'm geting the two concepts confused. How do I adjust for different sizes? Everything I've learnt from online tutorials and reading documentation only seems to account for density adjustments.

Comment: "How do I adjust for different sizes?" -- have different layouts for those sizes in suitable resource directories (e.g., `res/layout/` for smaller screens, `res/layout-w640dp/` for screens whose current width is 4" or higher). See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. Or, use a single layout that takes changing sizes into account, using the techniques outlined by Mr. Orlowski in his answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

dp doesn't stand for display pixels, but density-independent pixels. Said that not all displays make available the same quantity of dp's, therefore if you exceed the dp resolution of a device your layouts won't be rendered as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect container to shrink you cannot specify exact dimensions, because otherwise your element

```
android:layout_width="85dp"
android:layout_height="85dp"
```

will always take 85dp. And if screen size if higher then you will gaps as on 1st screen shot, bit you got smaller screen certain items can be clipped or even completely off screen.

In your case perhaps you should set all widths to `match_parent` and then set `layout_weight="1"` on each element in one container so it would spread. And if you want to use `RelativeLayout` you need to put all `ImageViews` into additional `LinearLayout` to make correct use of `layout_weight`

Comment: Do dp units not adapt to different sized screens? From what I read of the documentation I gathered that for a 720px screen 1dp would span 2pxs whilst for a 360px screen 1dp would consist of 1px?

Comment: @Deco: "Do dp units not adapt to different sized screens?" -- no, they adapt to different *densities*.

Comment: I want gaps between each element. I've tried using linear layouts as containers but my margins face the same problems my element dimensions face now.
Is it possible to set my elements location and dimensions based on being x% of the screens total width? Is using multiple layout files the more common approach to this problem? I miss xib files :p